# Get height of hidden fluid element on window resize with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, resize, height, fluid-layout

I am building a high-content WordPress blog, with a sidebar of articles that displays the excerpt of that article on hover. I use jQuery to get the element height (to avoid jQuery's common jumping issue with slideDown) then hide the element with this code:

```
function articleHeight() {
    $(".article").each(function() {
            $(this).css("height", $(this).height());
    });
}

articleHeight();
```

and then the following code to TRY and get the new height upon window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    articleHeight();
});
```

The first part works great, but it won't recalculate the size, causing it to either provide too much room, or cut the excerpt off upon resize.

I realize that since the element is already hidden, it may not be able to get the new height, but I tested this by un-hiding the element in the jQuery, and it still won't recalculate.

Any idea on this would be extremely helpful. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to give `$(this)` the same height it already had?

```
$(this).css("height", $(this).height() );
```

You have to compare it against `$(window).height()` for the new size, and then use some math to differentiate it.

Like this for example:

```
$(this).css("height", $(window).height() - 200 );
```

You would change the `200` to something that works for your page.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that outerHeight works for you, but I'd be more inclined to play about with the display property. Inline-block might fix it for you.

Here is the jquery outerHeight documentation
http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how the UI will work, but I've created a jsFiddle that you can use to fix your problem I hope:

http://jsfiddle.net/RqqpK/1/

Your article elements are now extended with extra functionality that you can use for desired behaviour and storing state with each element.

Ofcourse, it's better to use addClass() than css({height: ...}) and there are other improvements that you will benefit from when your code grows bigger, but this is a start. Good luck